# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

i have an error

```
File "logins3", line 17, in <module>
    my_inputs = soup.findall('input')
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

my code

```
# extract the token

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content)
my_inputs = soup.findall('input')

for input in my_inputs:
    print input.name + input['value'] #is here
```

the information

```
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="ovL2FuaW1lZGlnaXRhbG5ldHdvcmsuZZXgucGhwL2Nvbm5leGlvbg==" />
    <input type="hidden" name="8d900dda34d7a3d37252b4a3c8" value="1" />
```

i need this token  for create my script and I do not see how to fix it

ty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `_` before `a` in `soup.findall`

```
my_inputs = soup.find_all('input')
```

OR

```
>>> my_inputs = soup.findAll('input')
>>> for in_put in my_inputs:
        print in_put.name , in_put['value']


input ovL2FuaW1lZGlnaXRhbG5ldHdvcmsuZZXgucGhwL2Nvbm5leGlvbg==
input 1
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a typo.

You meant to use [`find_all()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all) instead of `findall()`.

---

FYI, it didn't fail with `AttributeError` here because the dot notation in `BeautifulSoup` has a special meaning - `soup.findall` is basically shortcut to `soup.find("findall")`. In other words, it tried to find an element with `findall` name, failed and returned `None`. This is how you've got `'NoneType' object is not callable`.